# How do I flatten out a small, localized bump on a concrete subfloor?

Tags: concrete

I am laying some laminate flooring in my basement and after I ripped up the carpet I found a rather large bump on the concrete subfloor.  I need to flatten this thing out so I can lay laminate on top of it.

Note that I am not trying to **level** the floor - I'm just trying to make it **have no bumps**.

What's the best way to remove this concrete bump?  Should I chisel it out?

Tried to upload a picture, but imgur keeps rejecting it (yes, it's under the size limit, by a lot).  I'll try again later.  Just imagine a concrete floor with a little acne.

Comment: I have this same problem.  Installing new flooring and there is a very noticeable hump in the concrete.  I imagine the only solution is to hammer it down below level with a handheld jack hammer or air hammer and then fill it in flat with some type of portland cement.

Comment: Do you have a large grinder you could fit a [diamond cup wheel](http://www.harborfreight.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/image_1781.jpg) to?

Comment: @brhans I do not have a grinder.   I have rotary and oscillatory dremels, however.

Comment: Weeell ... a decent grinder with a 7" wheel could level out some bumps in minutes. A dremel ... well how many hours do you want to spend on it and how many times do you want to replace the teeny tiny grinding disc/wheel/thingy?

Comment: @brhans haha ok no dremel then.   Could I chisel it out with an old flathead screw driver?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't particularly value that poor screwdriver - and this would probably be about as effective as the dremel. So choose your poison ...

Comment: Get a cold chisel for concrete and heavy hammer to drive it. Or get one of those 5 or 6 ft steel bars. All seem have a spade or chisel on one end, but on the other end some have a point and others have an earth tamper. I'd think you want the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A silicon carbide rubbing block. I'd swear this is a duplicate but it's not showing up in the "related" links.

[image: rubbing brick]

Inexpensive hand tool, makes short work of bumps, by hand. Use some water to lubricate and prevent dust while grinding.

Comment: Not what I used in this particular case, but this answer seems more "right" than my solution.

Comment: They work pretty well, and yet I managed to get through a number of decades before I found out about them. I suppose I must have walked past them quite a few times, but I never "saw" them as I would have had no idea what they were for...

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, I was able to use a cold chisel and a hammer, as @Jim Stewart suggested, to chisel it out.  It was a pretty small patch and it didn't take long at all.