# Can these concrete protrusions be removed without a grinder?

Tags: concrete, basement

My basement walls have these bumps all over them. They're every 2 feet horizontally, and about every 2 feet vertically. I'm guessing this is an artifact of the rebar.

I'd like to reduce the max protrusion to 1/4" or less before installing [InSoFast](https://www.insofast.com). Right now they're closer to 1/2."

I imagine I could use a concrete grinder, but that would make a big mess.

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/109469/18078 Those are form tie bumps, not rebar related.

Comment: I mean, if it's me I'm just grabbing a hammer and bashing them flat, then breaking out the vacuum to suck up all the bits.

Comment: Use the square face of a rock hammer, striking downwards. 3 out of 4 hits will miss. The fourth will pop it right off.

Comment: How old is the basement concrete?  This task would be easier with younger/green concrete vs something that's been there for years.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your options are dust or chips.

An angle grinder with a diamond wheel would make quick work of it, but you'd want a helper holding a good shop vac directly in the line of fire.

Otherwise, a cold chisel and a chunky hammer will do (or a rotary hammer in non-rotating mode). Chips will fly, but dust will be minimal.

Use eye, ear, and lung protection as appropriate.

Comment: If grinding, you should wear a respirator rated for silica dust in addition to the vacuum.

Comment: **(or a rotary hammer in non-rotating mode)** - Is this what we in the UK would call an SDS Drill

Comment: @ThaRobster Not directly. SDS refers to the interface between the power tool and the cutting/drilling/chisel implement, rather than whether the motion imparted is rotational, impact, or both.

Comment: "a helper holding a good shop vac directly in the line of fire" made me cringe.

Comment: I used a metal putty knife with a reinforced handle to smooth out a wall in my basement and it worked great.  It doesn't take much work at all to bust them off and smooth seams.  In my case I also filled in any of the air bubbles with dry-lock mortar and then painted with dry-lock paint.

Comment: I can see that working, but it'll destroy the knife edge.

Answer (score 9):

Another (more manual) option is a **rubbing brick**.

They're often billed as being used to remove form marks, which is likely what you have there.  It's a handheld piece of silicon carbide or something similarly harder than concrete, used to perform minor abrasions and smooth rough edges of concrete castings.

They're available at most home improvement stores in the concrete tool aisle:
[image: Concrete rubbing block]

Comment: That's gonna be a hell of a lot of hard work, if the concrete is decent!

Comment: Yeah, these are best for _smoothing_, not shaping.

Comment: Use cold chisel first. Plus usual comment about protective equipment.